# boolen expression and side effects

Tags: haskell, boolean-expression, side-effects

I hope everyone is safe.

I am learning Haskell and came upon the fact that a function in Haskell has no side-effect. I just wondered in imperative languages are boolean expression considered to be expression with no side-effects since they only return true or false (their main effect)

Thanks!

Comment: A function can have side effects, for example if you call a function that writes to a file, inserts a record in a database, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an imperative language, expressions can normally have side-effects. For example in Python:

```
def f(x):
    print(x)
    return True

if f(2) or f(4):
    print(3)
```

Here it thus prints to the standard output channel, which is a side-effect. It can also do file I/O, insert records in a database, perform network I/O, insert elements in a list, create a process, and other forms of side effects.

Regardless the type of the expression, it can normally have side effects. In *safe* Haskell, one can normally not perform any I/O, unless you make use of an `IO`, so then it is `IO Bool`, not `Bool`. Furthermore all variables are immutable, hence you can not add elements to a list, you can construct a new list, but then there are no effects for readers of the "old" list.

If you of course specify that they *only* return `True` or `False`, and thus do not have any side-effects, then a boolean expression has no side effects, since `not`, `and`, `or`, etc. normally have no side-effects either. But the problem is that you can not say if a function has side-effects in Python (and other imperative languages) based on the return type.

The idea that functions have no side-effects enables a lot of optimizations the compiler can do. For example in Haskell everything is evaluated lazily, that means that unless you need to know the value of something, it remains unevaluated. This is possible since the order of evaluating functions with no side-effects is not important. If a function can not alter a list that is accessible by another function, then it thus can not have impact on the result of that list.

It furthermore makes it easier to run things in parallel, since again, a function with no side-effects, can not have impact on the results of another function, hence the two functions can be evaluated by different cores.

But perhaps the most useful consequence is that it makes programs very modular, and less error-prone. A lot of bugs result from the fact that a function makes changes to an object, database, etc. and that the function later in the program did not anticipate on these changes. For example if a function removes a record from the database, then the next function might work under the assumption that this record is still there.

Comment: So basically its not about the expression its about the rules of the programming languages in determining which expressions have side-effects and which don't. Why doesn't Haskell or other functional programming languages don't allow (fundamentally) any side-effects? aren't they useful in creating complexion and abstractions?

Comment: @ZeevKeane: it is helpful not to have any side-effects. For example it means Haskell can implement "automatic" lazy programming: so instead of the programmer having to specify what can be lazily done, the compiler can do it, since it does not matter if something is evaluated or not for the results of other functions.

Comment: @ZeevKeane: updated with some advantages of functions having no side-effects. Especially in JavaScript there is lately some interesting in programming in a functional manner, to avoid bugs that have to do with these side-effects. See for example: https://opensource.com/article/17/6/functional-javascript

Comment: So basically there is less need to prove the program since it's functions don't have any side-effects (if I understand it correctly its like going back to first principles because its mathematically easier to prove the correctness of the work, right?).

Comment: @ZeevKeane: it basically means that you have to worry about less parameters, environment things, and thus it makes it easier to derive properties, and thus optimize programs yes.

Comment: @ZeevKeane Yes, having the purity noted/enforced by the type-system means you don't have to rely on convention/best practices/your colleagues to do the right thing. It reduces your cognitive load by allowing you to make safer assumptions about the behaviour of other code, without having to read it.

Comment: @ZeevKeane One possible way to see it is: Haskell does not really forbid side effects, we can always return `IO Bool` and pretend to be imperative. What Haskell allows, beyond that, is to use a type which guarantees no-side-effects, namely `Bool`. Seen in this way, imperative languages only have `IO Bool`, while in Haskell we can choose between the two. One might even argue that, because of this, Haskell gives us more flexibility, while imperative languages restrict the programmer to use `IO Bool`, only, even for pure functions. This is a stretch, but technically it is true.

Comment: @ZeevKeane Note, I'm not arguing that Haskell is "superior" to imperative languages. I'm only saying that Haskell, in a sense, gives the programmer the "option to restrict themselves" to pure code when they want, and have the compiler help ensuring the restrictions are followed. Some programmers like having the option of doing that, others prefer to have fewer constraints. Technically, no approach is strictly better, it's a pure matter of taste.